# 1GB Vector, will Vector.Unboxed give trouble, will Vector.Storable give trouble?

Tags: haskell

We need to store a large 1GB of contiguous bytes in memory for long periods of time (weeks to months), and are trying to choose a Vector/Array library.  I had two concerns that I can't find the answer to.

1. Vector.Unboxed seems to store the underlying bytes on the heap, which can be moved around at will by the GC....  Periodically moving 1GB of data would be something I would like to avoid.
2. Vector.Storable solves this problem by storing the underlying bytes in the c heap.  But everything I've read seems to indicate that this is really only to be used for communicating with other languages (primarily c).  Is there some reason that I should avoid using Vector.Storable for internal Haskell usage.

I'm open to a third option if it makes sense!

Comment: Whenever I see strange use cases like this my first thought is "are they using the right data structure?".  So, why do you need to store it in memory for such long periods of time?  Do you need very fast random access?  Could you split it up into many smaller vectors, say 10MB chunks, which could be moved around by the GC without you noticing?  It wouldn't be too difficult to write a simple wrapper around indexing/mapping with it.  An `IntMap (Vector a)` would probably be suitable for that.

Comment: @bheklilr I believe the answers is, yes it makes sense....  It is for Ethereum mining, described here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash.  It is a very clever ASIC resistant algo which uses memory as a bottleneck.  Since it is mining, speed matters.  The basic idea is that we are forced to precalculate a large array (which will change every couple weeks or so), then perform random access across the array for each new block a predetermined number of steps, over and over again.  Since milliseconds matter, I don't want to fiddle with the predetermined cache once it is set.

Comment: that sounds like a very legitimate use case then. Just making sure. There may be options to the RTS and some pragmas that would prevent the gc from touching it.

Comment: @bheklilr thanks....  Would it just make more sense to use Data.Vector.Storable, which has more fine grained access over what gets moved or not?

Comment: I do not have the ability to answer that question.  This might be a good one to ask over on IRC and/or reddit, just to reach a larger audience.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was [the `mmap` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmap), which allows you to "memory-map" a file into memory, using the virtual memory system to manage paging. I don't know if this is appropriate for your use case (in particular, I don't know if you're *loading* or *computing* this 1GB of data), but it may be worth looking at.

In particular, I *think* this prevents the GC moving the data around (since it's not on the Haskell heap, it's managed by the OS virtual memory subsystem). On the other hand, this interface handles only raw bytes; you couldn't have, say, an array of `Customer` objects or something.

Comment: It is an interesting thought.  The data is being computed, but it might make sense saving the data in a file to be used for the time period it is needed....  Then if we stop the program, it will be ready to use immediately.  I will look into this package a big.